# Inconsistent result from Get-CsOnlineUser

Tags: powershell, skype-for-business

The property OnlineVoiceRoutingPolicy returned in powershell is inconsistent. Either i'm doing something wrong with when selecting based on identity, or theres a bug i'm unaware of.

When not selecting from identity i get something like this:

```
Get-CsOnlineUser | Select-Object -Property OnlineVoiceRoutingPolicy, UserPrincipalName

OnlineVoiceRoutingPolicy UserPrincipalName
------------------------ -----------------
DK                       user1@test.it
...//other similar users
```

But when i use the -Identity argument:

```
Get-CsOnlineUser -Identity user1@test.it | Select-Object -Property OnlineVoiceRoutingPolicy, UserPrincipalName

OnlineVoiceRoutingPolicy UserPrincipalName
------------------------ -----------------
                         user1@test.it
```

This happens fo all users, if i get the collection of users, OnlineVoiceRoutingPolicy is correctly set, but if i get a specific user, it's blank.

Any suggestions as to why this happens ?

Comment: In [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/skype/get-csonlineuser?view=skype-ps) I see this note on parameter `-Identity`: _"Note that in Microsoft Teams PowerShell Version 2.5.1, using this parameter will cause the Get-CsOnlineUser command to no longer emit deprecated properties as part of the modernization effort."_. Can that be the cause?

Comment: OnlineVoiceRoutingPolicy is not on the list of deprecated from teh description on that same doc page. It could be that it's just missing from that list, and is omitted by mistake, or is intended to be deprecated.

Comment: Yes, your guess is as good as mine. Sometimes documentation is incomplete..